# How to get and move the parent window of an EditorManager in Qt Creator src?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have 1 instance of Qt Creator open with 2 floating windows (Open in New Window). This gives me a total of 3 "editor windows". Each "editor window" has 3 horizontal splits, giving me +-9 open documents. I have this spread over 3 monitors like this [image: this].

I usually hibernate my workstation but if I have a crash and have to reboot or I open the project on a different machine I lose the floating windows and the documents in their splits and the position of the scroll in those documents and I have to manually start over rearranging everything. **I'm looking to save and recall this floating win position and editor view split data on project load**.

To fix this, I've been building Qt Creator from source. My first task is to move the initial (or floating) window. I've tracked down some stuff but **I can't find the "parent widget" of the EditorManager which is the "editor manager" alluded to above**. Thus, just the editor managers move, which obviously I don't want. **How do I access and move the initial parent window and the floating windows?**

```
//editormanager.cpp

void EditorManagerPrivate::restoreFloatingWindows()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->m_editorAreas.size(); ++i)
    {
       d->m_editorAreas[i]->move(100, 100); // don't want to move this
       d->m_editorAreas[i]->parentWidget()->move(100, 100); //no effect

        qDebug() << "pos" << d->m_editorAreas[i]->pos();
        qDebug() << "pos parentWidget" << d->m_editorAreas[i]->parentWidget()->pos();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `QWidgets` have a pointer to the containing window, as of Qt 5.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window

As far as storing and recalling geometry and states, these methods are extremely useful:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState

When using `QSettings`, start an array, and then push these values for each window.  Or when you are loading the project, pull each value and use the appropriate setter.

Hope that helps.